# Migrate from (old) Testflight to Hockey App

Tags: ios, testflight, hockeyapp

Is there an easy way to migrate from the old Testflight to HockeyApp?
I know that i can export the users from Testflight, but can i import them to HockeyApp?

Comment: Read this: http://hockeyapp.net/blog/2014/03/12/migrate-from-testflight.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close your vote, as this is clearly a relevant question.

Comment: You can also found this tool useful for you https://github.com/Touchwonders/testflight-exporter